# Import data from javascript file to VB.Net page

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, json

Any information about how to solve the following problem would be appreciated

I am trying to transfer data from a javascript file to a VB.Net application using JSON.

The code in the javascript file is as follows:

```
function TalkToServer() {

    var formData = "{'firstname':'fname','lastname':'dgln'}"


        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "dataserver.aspx/Save",
            data: "{'firstname':'fname','lastname':'dgln'}",
            contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (msg) {
                alert('Hello');
            },
            error: function () { alert(arguments[2]); }
        });

}
```

The VB.Net code is as follows:

```
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.Linq
Imports System.Web
Imports System.Web.Services
Imports System.Web.Script.Serialization
Imports System.Web.Script.Services

Imports System.Web.UI
Imports System.Web.UI.WebControls

Public Class dataserver

Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

End Sub

<WebMethod()> _
<ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat:=ResponseFormat.Json, UseHttpGet:=False)> _
Public Function Save(ByVal formData As williedata) As returnMessages
    'Public Function Save(ByVal name As String) As returnMessages

    Dim a As String = formData.firstname
    Dim b As String = formData.lastname


    Dim mes As returnMessages
    mes.returnParameters = "KLJN"
    mes.recAction = "JKHJH"

    Return mes



End Function



End Class
```

The definition of the datastructure is as follows:

```
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic

Public Class williedata


Public lastname As String
Public firstname As String

End Class
```

However - it seems as if the VB.Net function is never reached. The following error keeps appering:

Internal Server Error

I know I am doing something wrong but cannot figure out what.

WCV

Comment: Are you sure you URL is `dataserver.aspx` and not `dataserver.asmx`? And if it is correct did you try debugging and setting a breakpoint in your method?

Comment: Yes it is dataserver.aspx, a normal asp page. I tried to set a break point in the method but it is never reached WCV

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Remove the `""` so you pass a literal object to JQuery:  `data: {'firstname':'fname','lastname':'dgln'}`.</strike>

Since you set the `contentType` as JSON, JQuery should parse it properly from an object literal.  Since you are currently passing a string, that is not valid JSON, it could not be encoding it properly.

**Edit**

As the other answer indicates I was mistaken, the `data` parameter needs to be in the format indictated by `contentType` so in this case valid JSON:

`data: '{"firstname":"fname","lastname":"dgln"}'`

Comment: @user1672071 are you using a tool like firebug or fiddler to examine the request headers of your ajax request, if so post the request and response, if not I urge you to familiarize yourself with one of these tools, most issues like this are solved by info gathered this way.

Comment: The quoted data parameter is necessary. If you pass an object literal through jQuery's data parameter, jQuery will URL encode the data, not JSON stringify it. That will cause ASP.NET to throw an Invalid JSON Primitive error since it's expecting JSON and the POST data will be URL encoded (more info: http://encosia.com/asmx-scriptservice-mistake-invalid-json-primitive/)

Comment: @DaveWard You are right I updated my answer to correct my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Your data parameter needs to match the method signature closer:

```
data: '{"formData":{"firstname":"fname", "lastname":"dgln"}}'
```

You can [use JSON.stringify to simplify that process](http://encosia.com/using-complex-types-to-make-calling-services-less-complex/).

Comment: Thank you all very much for the feedback. I shall try it first thing tomorrow morning. It is getting a bit late now - I cannot concentrate any more. WCV